# Speeding up dataframe.to_excel operations by a GPU

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, google-cloud-platform, gpu

I was working on extracting some data wherein I constantly need to manipulate some part of fetched data and then append it to another dataframe which contains the combined dataset. I constantly save the dataframe using dataframe.to_excel. Since there is a lot of data, it has started to become a time taking operation, reading the previous file, appending and saving it again, inspite of ample of CPU and RAM. I am using GCP, an N1 type 8vCPU along a 30GB memory. Moreover since I am running various instances of the same script for various projects together, would using a GPU speed these things up ?

Answer (score 1):

I never did it by myself but I think this is possible by using some Pandas alternative.
I found this [thread](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-accelerate-Pandas-DataFrame-data-analysis-with-GPU#:%7E:text=Pandas%20does%20not%20have%20GPU,used%20by%20libraries%20like%20Spacy.) which users seems to provide some solutions to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

I too have not tried this. I could offer couple of suggestions

- rather than to_excel try to use to_csv probably there might be small gains.
- you can try this library https://github.com/modin-project/modin, this library seems to make the read and operations faster, but i am not sure able to the write operations.
- or you could move it to to_excel line to a different function and perform that operation by spinning out a new thread.